# Node js , express-rate-limiter is not working properly

Tags: node.js

I want to restrict `POST` requests hit to 5 requests per 10 sec , per user session.
I have implemented express rate limiter, But i am able to hit more than 5 requests. Till 4-5 sec, it will block req. but after that i am again able to hit more requests.

Below is the code :

```
const ThrottleLimiter = require("express-rate-limit");
const limiter = ThrottleLimiter({
    windowMs: 10000,
    max: 5,
    headers: false,
    handler:(req,res,next)=>{
        res.status(HTTP.tooManyRequests.code).json(HTTP.tooManyRequests);
      }

  });
  app.post("/*", limiter);
```

Comment: Kindly refer to this [ask].

Answer (score 0):

express-rate-limit works like this here: 
If you've made your 1st request in second 1 
and your 5th request on second 6 
then it will block you from making more requests till second 11(**your first request time + 10 seconds**)
and **Not** second 16(your last request time + 10 seconds)
but it works fine on average

Comment: yes , you are right but that is also not happening , its not blocking till 10 sec. after i hit the first request